# jquery mobile header two buttons on right

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, header

i need two buttons on the right site of the header. how it looks like now is

[image]

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" >
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div class="ui-btn-right">
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="delete">Cancel</a>
            <a href="#" data-icon="gear" >Options</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So what is wrong? why i get just text and not my buttons?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: okay my fault.. forget to add data-role="button" to my a tag.. Anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay my fault.. forget to add data-role="button" to my a tag